# Annotating a Vinyl stream in Gulp with additional metadata

Tags: gulp

What is the correct approach to writing a Gulp plugin that could annotate a stream with additional metadata that is then used later in the pipeline?

For example, an image resizer plugin might take as options an array of sizes to create `[32,64,128]`. It could then emit each file passed to `(A, B, ...)`it multiple times, one for each image size set in the options: `A+{s:32}, A+{s:64}, A+{s:128}, B+{s:32}, B+{s:64}, B+{s:128}`. A later gulp plugin would see that metadata and resize the image accordingly.

The Vinyl `File` object doesn't appear to support additional metadata so how is one meant to achieve this kind of processing with Gulp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can add custom properties to a vinyl file and those will be preserved. For example [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#example) depends on that.

Docs for vinyl clone says: "Returns a new File object with all attributes cloned. Custom attributes are deep-cloned."

https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl#clone

Comment: Thanks. My plugin is passing tests, and the clone method does seem to retain any additional properties I add. https://bitbucket.org/ianmercer/gulp-cartesian/